# Как найти элемент по его html коду? (selenium)

Tags: html5, selenium, python-3.5

Допустим есть код кнопки:

```
<button onclick="console.log('Clicked!');">Test button</button>
```

И сам код страницы:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <button onclick="console.log('Clicked!');">Test button</button>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .content {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .content button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 20px;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Как с помощью selenium python получить кнопку по её html коду?

Comment: Самый простой способ - это распарсить html код кнопки и получить переменные class, id, onclick и и тд (в данном только onclick), а потом с помощью обычных методов (типа find_element_by_css_selector, /xpath и тд) найти элемент. Но это не совсем то, что я хочу получить, есть ли более элегантные способы решения?